# grep early stop with one match per pattern

Tags: awk, grep

Say I have a file where the patterns reside, e.g. **patterns.txt**. And I know that all the patterns will only be matched once in another file **patterns_copy.txt**, which in this case to make matters simple is just a copy of **patterns.txt**.

If I run

```
grep -m 1 --file=patterns.txt patterns_copy.txt > output.txt
```

I get only one line. I guess it's because the **m** flag stopped the whole matching process once the 1st line of the two files match.

What I would like to achieve is to have each pattern in **patterns.txt** matched only once, and then let grep move to the next pattern.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: With `awk`, is the short answer!

Comment: @MarkSetchell, can you elaborate a little please? I am not familiar with awk actually. Thanks.

Comment: It's late - maybe @EdMorton would do it for you, or I'll do it tomorrow. Try editing your tags and adding `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I have now had a chance to integrate what I was thinking about `awk` into the `GNU Parallel` concept.

I used `/usr/share/dict/words` as my `patterns` file and it has 235,000 lines in it. Using BenjaminW's code in another answer, it took 141 minutes, whereas this code gets that down to 11 minutes.

The difference here is that there are no temporary files and `awk` can stop once it has found all 8 of the things it was looking for...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a bash function that GNU Parallel can call to search for 8 things at once
doit() {
   # echo Job: $9
   # In following awk script, read "p1s" as a flag meaning "p1 has been seen"
   awk -v p1="$1" -v p2="$2" -v p3="$3" -v p4="$4" -v p5="$5" -v p6="$6" -v p7="$7" -v p8="$8" '
      $0 ~ p1 && !p1s {print; p1s++;}
      $0 ~ p2 && !p2s {print; p2s++;}
      $0 ~ p3 && !p3s {print; p3s++;}
      $0 ~ p4 && !p4s {print; p4s++;}
      $0 ~ p5 && !p5s {print; p5s++;}
      $0 ~ p6 && !p6s {print; p6s++;}
      $0 ~ p7 && !p7s {print; p7s++;}
      $0 ~ p8 && !p8s {print; p8s++;}
      {if(p1s+p2s+p3s+p4s+p5s+p6s+p7s+p8s==8)exit}
   ' patterns.txt

}
export -f doit

# Next line effectively uses 8 cores at a time to each search for 8 items
parallel -N8 doit {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {#} < patterns.txt
```

Just for fun, here is what it does to my CPU - blue means maxed out, and see if you can see where the job started in the green CPU history!

[image]

**Other Thoughts**

The above benefits from the fact that the input files are relatively well sorted, so it is worth looking for 8 things at a time because they are likely close to each other in the input file, and I can therefore avoid the overhead associated with creating one process per sought term. However, if your data are not well sorted, that may mean that you waste a lot of time looking further through the file than necessary to find the next  7, or 6 other items. In that case, you may be better off with this:

```
parallel grep -m1 "{}" patterns.txt < patterns.txt
```

**Original Answer**

Having looked at the size of your files, I now think `awk` is probably not the way to go, but `GNU Parallel` maybe is. I tried parallelising the problem two ways.

Firstly, I search for 8 items at a time in a single pass through the input file so that I have less to search through with the second set of `grep`s that use the `-m 1` parameter.

Secondly, I do as many of these *"8-at-a-time"* `grep`s in parallel as I have CPU cores.

I use the GNU Parallel job number `{#}` as a unique temporary filename, and only create 16 (or however many CPU cores you have) temporary files at a time. The temporary files are prefixed `ss` (for sub-search) so they can call be deleted easily enough when testing.

The speedup seems to be a factor of about 4 times on my machine. I used `/usr/share/dict/words` as my test files.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a bash function that GNU Parallel can call to search for 8 things at once
doit() {
   # echo Job: $9
   # Make a temp filename using GNU Parallel's job number which is $9 here
   TEMP=ss-${9}.txt
   grep -E "$1|$2|$3|$4|$5|$6|$7|$8" patterns.txt > $TEMP
   for i in $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8; do
      grep -m1 "$i" $TEMP
   done
   rm $TEMP

}
export -f doit

# Next line effectively uses 8 cores at a time to each search for 8 items
parallel -N8 doit {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {#} < patterns.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I haven't tried out the solution you gave yet, but the doit function seem to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your patterns like this (assuming you're using Bash):

```sh
while read -r line; do
    grep -m 1 "$line" patterns_copy.txt
done < patterns.txt > output.txt
```

Or, in one line:

```
while read -r line; do grep -m 1 "$line" patterns_copy.txt; done < patterns.txt > output.txt
```

For parallel processing, you can start the processes as background jobs:

```sh
while read -r line; do
    grep -m 1 "$line" patterns_copy.txt &
    read -r line && grep -m 1 "$line" patterns_copy.txt &
    # Repeat the previous line as desired
    wait # Wait for greps of this loop to finish
done < patterns.txt > output.txt
```

This is not really elegant as for each loop it will wait for the slowest grep to finish, but should still be faster than just one grep per loop.

Comment: That's cool! Now if the file where I'll try to search through is large (the patterns_copy.txt file, in the range of Gb), is there a fast way to do it? I tried GNU parallel in it but the results are not right. Thanks!

Comment: You could read a few lines at a time and then start `grep` as a background process with `grep ... &`. GNU parallel is probably the cleaner solution, but I'm not familiar with it.